# Default Crystal Text Field Height

Tags: crystal-reports, report

In Crystal Reports 2011 when I create a new text field and add it in design view the height is 0.13.  Other instances of Crystal I've seen always create these fields at a height of 0.16.  How do I set my instance of Crystal to create fields at this height?

Comment: Should be moved to superuser? I don't know Crystal Reports, but it seems to be no programming but a software question.

Comment: Not sure if this is right or not, but try File -> Options -> Fonts tab, and change the default values of the different types of fields.  My Crystal XI (which is still default) is set to Arial 10pt for everything.

Comment: @EvilBob22 - trying it out, your suggestion works for fields, but not text objects

Comment: @Chris - I was thinking about the "Fonts" tab, not the "Fields" tab.  The fonts tab has an option for text objects.  I was able to set default _font_ sizes that way in Crystal 9 and XI -- although not a default _field_ height.

Comment: @EvilBob22 - I'm referring to the Fonts tab too - there's a button on there for fields (changing the font affects default height) and for text objects (changing font there does not affect default height).

Comment: @Chris I see what you are saying, yes you are correct.

Comment: What is your windows screen DPI?

Answer (score 1):

you have to change the hight or width your self, and if you want to change more than one textboxes, select them and then right click on them move cursor on "align" and select your choice or you can choose same size for all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can change the default height of a text object. I've never tried this before but you might be able to use CSS to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how you got into this situation - I've looked all over and can't find a way to modify the default height of a text object in the version you're using (and it is 0.16 inches for my install).

Assuming reinstalling is out of the question (this would be drastic but is probably your best bet), an alternative workaround may be to create an empty text object at the top of a report, manually set it to the correct height, then copy-pasting it anywhere you want a new one instead of using the insert menu.